# Regex - Replace specific zeros in a string before a period

Tags: c#, regex

sorry for such a direct question but i've spent a little too long trying to find a suitable RegEx that can alter the following strings:

- 01.10
- 10.01

setting them as:

- 1.10
- 10.1

So basically always remove the first '0' in the complete sequence before each period, or in the last sequence.

Is this possible with RegEx as currently it doesn't seem so?

Comment: What about `0.5` or `0.0`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

find: `(^|\.)0+`

replace: `$1`

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/iBFayx/1) a demo

Note: if the expression is **not** at the beginning of the string, you should not use `^`, but the word boundary `\b`, like this:

```
(\b|\.)0+
```

eventually, double escape it:

```
(\\b|\.)0+
```

See [other demo](https://regex101.com/r/iBFayx/2)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try it using this regex. This will not match the zero in 0.0 or 0.1 but only when there are digits after the leading zero(s).

[`\b0+(?=\d\.\d+\b)|(?<=\b\d+\.)0+(?=\d+\b)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb0%2b%28%3f%3d%5cd%5c.%5cd%2b%5cb%29%7c%28%3f%3c%3d%5cb%5cd%2b%5c.%290%2b%28%3f%3d%5cd%2b%5cb%29&i=01.10%0d%0a10.01%0d%0a001.10%0d%0a001.01%0d%0a0001.0001%0d%0atest01.10%0d%0a01.01test%0d%0a01.1test%0d%0atest0.01%0d%0atest1.01%0d%0a0.9%0d%0atest01.10%0d%0a0.9000%0d%0a0.5%0d%0a0.0%0d%0athis+is+0+times)

- `\b` word boundary
- `0+(?=\d\.\d+\b)` match a zero and use a positive lookahead to assert that the zero is followed by a digit, dot, one or more digits and a word boundary
- `|` Or
- `(?<=\b\d+\.)0+(?=\d+\b)` Positive lookbehind that asserts that what is on the left is a wordboundary, one or more digits and a dot. Then match one or more zeroes and assert that what follows id one or more digits and a wordboundary.